# Find and Append feature in JetBrains/VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, jetbrains-ide

Is there some way to append something to a search result in JetBrains IDEs or VSCode?

Usually I'd use find and replace and just copy the old result and append things but now I am using regex search over multiple files and I need to add a line to all the results.

Usually using find and replace you'll get something like this:
[image: Find and replace]

So instead of replacing the search result I want my input to be added the search result.
[image: Find and add]
This should be useful when using RegEx to edit multiple lines that have things in common.
In my case I was looking to add a field to all my `enum`s that are like:

```cs
public enum EnumName {
   // field1
   // field2...
}
```

To be like :

```cs
public enum EnumName {
   // default field
   // field1
   // field2...
}
```

Comment: I suggest you clarify your issue by providing 1) what you have 2) what you do / intermediate results 3) what you want to have in the end. Right now I'm not sure what "append" functionality you have in mind...

Comment: **I guess** I understand what you want ... but to be sure: **please provide the actual code/text -- before and after** (e.g. I have `public class ZZZ`, I search for `public class` and I want it to become `final public class ZZZ` in the end.

Comment: Based on my guess so far: use regex with **capture groups** (part of the regex search pattern inside `()`) and then reference them in the Replace field with `$1`, `$2` and so on. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference

Comment: There is also a SSR (Structural Search & Replace) that can be used in certain complex cases (where regex will not do much etc.) Have a look: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html **P.S.** You seem to be doing a search in Python files. I do not know how well it is supported by SSR (not a Python user). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/structural-search-and-replace.html

Comment: @LazyOne it's actually C# not Python but thanks for the pointers, I'll look them up and see if that works.

Comment: Apparently the SSR isn't available in Rider but for my case RegEx capturing groups worked as I wanted, you have my thanks for that. Could you please add what you said in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: 1) Not using Rider myself either. But Rider Help pages have the mentioning of the SSR (only in a few places only though; perhaps it has a different name there): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#CodeTemplateAttribute

Comment: 2) Please post your own answer (with examples of your actual search/replace patterns). I only gave you the pointer but not the actual solution. And I do not use the IDE (and the language) that you have to check all that. A question with an answer will be more visible in search results and will help other users with a similar need. You can accept your own answer after some delay (1 or 2 days I believe, it depends on your rep points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne replies, I've been able to find a way to do what I am looking for by using [RegEx Capturing Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) that works in JetBrains IDEs ([Intellij help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference)) and [VSCode](https://linuxpip.org/vscode-regex-replace/#:%7E:text=Add%20suffix%20to-,lines,-Similarly%2C%20knowing%20that) too.
It consists on putting the regular expression we want to add something to in parenthesis in the `search` field and then in the `replace` field using `$1` `$2`.. to reference the RegExs given the actual order in the search.
In my case using Jetbrains Rider I was looking to add something to all the `enum`s in my solution, and I simply put my RegEx inside `()` so it became `(.* enum .* .*\{)` and then used `$1` to reference it like this:
[image: Find and append using RegEx]